# AssetBundle dependency class is not found

Tags: php, yii2, assets

I've created a dependency in `@app/assets/dependencies` named `UikitDependency.php` which has `app\assets\dependencies` namespace:

```
namespace app\assets\dependencies;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class UikitDependency extends AssetBundle
{
    public $sourcePath = '@bower/uikit/';
    public $css = [
        'css/uikit.almost-flat.min.css',
    ];
}
```

Then I've tried to add this dependency to `@app/assets` asset which name is `MainAppAsset.php` and namespace is `app\assets` with following code:

```
public $depends = [
    'assets/dependencies/UikitDependency'
];
```

And after all it shows me an error says: ***Class assets/dependencies/UikitDependency does not exist***

I've also tried:

```
public $depends = [
    'dependencies/UikitDependency'
];
```

and:

```
public $depends = [
    '@app/assets/dependencies/UikitDependency'
];
```

I hadn't found any documentation about dependencies paths at the moment I asked it here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
public $depends = [
    'app\assets\dependencies\UikitDependency'
];
```

Namespace is part of class name in PHP.